# how to change the color of a QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt

i have a scene with a multiple (QGraphicsTextItem)s, and  i need to have control over their colors , so how to change a color of a QGraphicsTextItem ? is it possible anyway? i've been trying for 3 days until now . please help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can change the text color by calling the method:

`void QGraphicsTextItem::setDefaultTextColor ( const QColor & col );`

You have an example [here](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/graphicsview-diagramscene/).

Or looking for *Diagram Scene Example* in your Qt Assistant.

Answer (score 2):

setDefaultTextColor(col) "Sets the color for unformatted text to col." The documentation is not clear about what "unformatted text" means.  I think it means: "all portions of the contents of the item that have not been styled."

The contents is a QTextDocument.

You style a part of a document using a QTextCursor.  You can't style the QTextDocument per se, only a part that is selected by a QTextCursor (but you can select the whole document.)

You can style a QTextCursor using method mergeCharFormat(QTextCharFormat)

The QTextCharFormat has methods:

- foreground().setColor(QColor)
- setForeground(QBrush)
- setTextOutline(QPen)

Foreground is a QBrush that paints several things including "text" (but better said: the fill of characters?)

One nuance is that certain newly constructed QBrush have (default to) QBrushStyle.NoBrush, which is transparent, even if you setColor().